# Excel Macro not working when I add a new Sub with same code

Tags: vba, excel

I am not going to send you the entire code, because it is just a block of code repeated a lot...  Below is the over all gist of the code, the line of code is repeated multiple times with the "Sheets" & "Shapes" changing when necessary. What it is doing is I have a list box(which has a list of items) every time you click a specific item, there are about 30 text boxes that populate a specific sub-item that is related to the list box item.

The problem is, it is working for the Sub ListBox1_Change Macro for one tab, but when I try to do this for a second tab in the same Excel file it says there is a parameter error. However, and this is the interesting part, when I actually click on the text box the parameter error pops up. I click okay, then it populates.

The code works, but it isn't working when I try to do it on a second tab. I have tried combining them into one Sub, but that didn't work at all. So I broke them out into two separate Subs. Any input would be nice.

```
Sub ListBox1_Change()
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox1", "W"
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox2", "X"
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox3", "Y"
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox4", "Z"
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox5", "AA"
  Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "TextBox6, "AB"
End Sub
```

Along with the Handle that is in the Module

```
Sub Handle_Change(sht As Worksheet, lbName, tbName, colAddr)

   Dim idx As Long, lb   As msforms.ListBox

   Set lb = sht.Shapes(lbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object

   idx = lb.ListIndex
   If idx <> -1 Then
       sht.Shapes(tbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = _
                     sht.Range(colAddr & idx + 1).Value
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to figure out which line is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, and I am unsure of what it could possibly be. When I got the first one to work, I just copied and pasted the rest and have done so for all 50. I will end up having about 100 total and 4 tabs.

Comment: So which line is causing the error?

Comment: Well, I guess I shouldve been more specific, I have stepped through it, but it did not show me which line of code is causing the problem... All it says is "System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809). The parameter is incorrect."

Comment: Yes, but *when* does it say this? What line of code is being executed at that time?

Comment: That only pops up when I click on a textbox... When I step through no errors show

Comment: I would place a break point at the beginning of ListBox2_Change(), then click the text box and step through. If the error is in the macro, this should allow you to identify which line is throwing the error.

Comment: It would also help if you can provide the exact language of the error.

Comment: How do you place a break point?

Comment: tmoore "System Error &H80070057 (-2147024809). The parameter is incorrect. That is exactly what it says

Comment: To place a break point, open your VBA editor, locate the macro you're debugging, and do one of the following: 1) left-click in the solid gray bar on the left, right in line with the line you want the code to break on. A maroon dot should appear, and it should highlight the line in the same color. 2) Right-click the line you want to break on, hover over "Toggle" in the  menu that comes up, and click "Breakpoint." There's also a button to toggle a breakpoint, but these are a little faster.

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: This question is beyond recovery I think - now that you've replaced the original code, none of the comments make much sense, and looking at what you're trying I don't think we're even working in the same direction. Please post a new question and let's see if we can resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You should refactor your code before you write any more.

**EDIT**: made a few changes after testing:

```
'These go in the relvant worksheet code module
Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox1", "TextBox1", "B"
End Sub

Sub ListBox2_Change()
    Handle_Change Me, "ListBox2", "TextBox2", "C"
End Sub    


'This goes in a *regular* code module
Sub Handle_Change(sht As Worksheet, lbName, tbName, colAddr)

    Dim idx As Long, lb   As msforms.ListBox

    Set lb = sht.Shapes(lbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object

    idx = lb.ListIndex
    If idx <> -1 Then
        sht.Shapes(tbName).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Text = _
                         sht.Range(colAddr & idx + 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity Tim, will I need to have a Handle_Change for every textbox?

Comment: You have only one single `Handle_Change` Sub - your other event handlers just call that, and pass in the variable parts.

Comment: Tim, I am working on your's and having some trouble. Every time I try to put the Sheet name in it says "Compile error: Expected: list separator or)" Not quite sure what that means...

Comment: Or am I supposed to do it word for word what you have? For the 'Handle listbox change (only need this once) section. I figured I was supposed to put whatever the names were

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make sure I get this. So just I am clear, the top code will go in to whichever sheet it belongs in. The Bottom code goes in the "ThisWorkbook" for the overall? Lastly, what is "Me"?

Comment: Yes to the first part. No to the second: place that code in a regular VBA module, not a worksheet module or the `ThisWorkbook` module.  In a worksheet module, `Me` refers to the worksheet object: it's easier to maintain compared to hard-coding the worksheet name as I originally had it.

Comment: Awesome, one last question. It isnt working with the above. I have moved the bottom into a module. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: I imagine this is how it should lookSub ListBox1_Change()
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "1", "W"
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "2", "X"
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "3", "Y"
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "4", "Z"
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "5", "AA"
    Handle_Change Me, "List Box 1", "6", "AB"
End Sub

Comment: It worked for me, so I'm not sure what your problem is.  You need one event handler for each list box, and each handler has only a single line of code, which calls Handle_Change, passing in `Me`, the name of the list box to which the event handler is responding, the name do the text box you want to populate, and the column letter(s) where you need to pull the info from.

Comment: So the above is what I have. When I try to click an item in the list box I get a popup that says: "Cannot run the macro "xx.xlsm!ThisWorkbook.ListBox1Change. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." I know they are not disabled and I have the code in the specific sheet in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.misc/i0TASoYOOWA), and the link to [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q171217), it sounds like the error you're seeing may be a result of the underscores in your macro names. This only seems to apply to Excel '97, though. If that's the version you're on, take out the underscores and see if the error goes away.

Comment: I have not.The above code are the only adjustments I have made. It is saying Compile error: User-defined type not defined. on line 2. Dim idx As Long....

Comment: Take the spaces out of "List Box 1" so it reads "ListBox1", and make sure you're starting the debug from `ListBox1_Change`, as that's where your arguments are coming from now.

Comment: Did what you suggested. the Compile error still popped up, only this time it highlighted "lb As msforms.ListBox" on the second line

Comment: Sounds like you're missing that type definition. 2 questions: What version of Excel are you using? '97? '03? '10? And when you click on Tools>References in the VBA editor, is the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library checked?